# tmux status line: use status-left for window-list, use middle-section for something else?

Tags: tmux, gnu-screen

I'm transitioning from GNU Screen to tmux, and trying to configure my tmux status line to mimic the caption I built in Screen.

My Screen caption has the list of windows on the left, hostname and loadavg roughly centered, and the session name on the right:

[image: GNU Screen 0]

The window-list stays left, the session name stays right, and the middle-section stays roughly centered, but nudges over to accommodate the window-list if it's long...
[image: GNU Screen 2]
[image: GNU Screen 6]

The closest I can get so far with tmux is:

```
set-window-option -g window-status-format ' #I #W'
set-window-option -g window-status-current-format ' #I #W'
set -g status-justify left
set -g status-left ''
set -g status-right '#h :: #(sysctl vm.loadavg | cut -d " " -f 3-5) #S '
```

yielding:
[image]
Is there a way to display the window-list in the `status-left` section and use the middle-section the way I want?

Comment: Do you want the the middle-section to stay fixed when status-left changes?

Comment: @lord.garbage Ideally yes, but I'm mostly wondering if it's possible to use the status-left section for the window-list.

Comment: Ah, that can be done. Sorry, I just saw that this was `screen` output. I was wondering why you were asking something which you already had. :) Sorry. Answer on the way.

Answer (score 3):

Setting this correctly is a bit tricky in `tmux`. But what you want is achieved by:

```
set -g status-right '#S'
# set-option -g status-left-length 30
set -g status-left '#I #W'
set-option -g status-justify centre


set-window-option -g window-status-current-format '#h :: #(sysctl vm.loadavg | cut -d " " -f 3-5)'
# Disable showing the default window list component.
set-window-option -g window-status-format '#h :: #(sysctl vm.loadavg | cut -d " " -f 3-5)'
```

This will give you the load average and hostname in the middle section for every window that you open. If you just want this to appear once and not for every new window again then you have to alter the last to lines:

```
`set-window-option -g window-status-current-format '#h :: #(sysctl vm.loadavg | cut -d " " -f 3-5)'`
```

and

```
 set `set-window-option -g window-status-format ''`
```

Let me elaborate on this a little. The lines `window-status-current-format` and `window-status-format` allow you to alter the `window` part of your status line. But you don't need to use window variables you can also use `#h` or any other stuff you want. The difference between `window-status-current-format` and `window-status-format` is that the former allows you to specify what is shown when the window in question is the current window and the latter when it is not. I prefer to set both and both to the same value. Once you have that part figured out you can easily format the left and right portion of your status line. Note that when you don't set `window-current-status-format` and `window-status-format` then `tmux` will show it's default window display option. Hence, even if you just want to get rid of the middle part because it interferes with your other settings you need to set both to `''`. `man tmux` is also very useful!

Comment: I don't know, for me that's showing a copy of the middle section (hostname and load) for each window created. I'll keep fiddling with it

Comment: Yes, as I said you can set your middle section to whatever you want by changing these to variables: `set-window-option -g window-status-current-format ''`, `set-window-option -g window-status-format '#h :: #(sysctl vm.loadavg | cut -d " " -f 3-5)'`.

Comment: And as far as I can see from your question that is exactly what you've asked for: "[…] trying to configure my tmux status line to mimic the caption I built in Screen. My Screen caption has the list of windows on the left, hostname and loadavg roughly centered, and the session name on the right […] there a way to display the window-list in the status-left section and use the middle-section the way I want?"

Comment: The closest to screen would be: `set-window-option -g window-status-current-format '#h :: #(sysctl vm.loadavg | cut -d " " -f 3-5)'` and set `set-window-option -g window-status-format ''`

Comment: Nice! Is it possible to still show all the open tmux windows in the left-most section of the status bar? Currently, it is just showing the active window.